# drag & drop in dojotoolkit

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

I am new to dojo. I have three divs; the first div has 10 pictures and other two divs are empty.

I want to allow the user to drag pictures to any div (2,3) or drag back to div1.

I want to store the pictures in a DB using PHP.

Comment: I might be able to help, if only I could understand the question.  Can you please rephrase your problem?

Comment: Sounds like you want someone to write your application for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the dragging and dropping, you'll need to use [`dojo.dnd.Source`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/dnd).

In your Js, you'll need:

```
dojo.require("dojo.dnd.Source");
```

Your HTML will look like this (for the most part):

```
<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" id="div1">
  <div class="dojoDndItem">
      <img />
  </div>
  <div class="dojoDndItem">
      <img />
  </div>
  ... 8 more times ...
</div>
```

I set up a simple example using google's logo that you can drag from one div to another [on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/efuqu).

As for saving to a database, I'm unclear on what you want to save.  The src?  Something else?

That being said, you could use [`dojo.query`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/query) to get the images of a certain div to call an [`xhrGet`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/xhrGet) to your PHP page/service.

Basically:

```
 dojo.query("img",dojo.byId("div1")).forEach( function() {
     // this is now the image
     dojo.xhrGet( { url: '/somepage.php',
                    data: { image_name: this.title } // ???: depends on what you want
                    load: function( data ) {
                      alert("I worked!");
                    },
                    error: function( data ) {
                       alert("O NOES!!!");
                    }
                }
    );
 });
```

Comment: Many Thanks
nice, that's what i need, a little problem with drag and drop when i start to drag image move little down and right which don't look good, can we fix it so its look like nice.